# Scala -cp doesn't work

Tags: scala, import

I'm trying to run a file called `test.scala` which refers to a library called `moarcoref-assembly-1.jar`. I'm very sure that the library jar file contains the class `edu.berkeley.nlp.coref.NumberGenderComputer` but scala keeps complaining at the import command. It even doesn't seem to find the `edu` package.

```
$ cat test.scala
import java.io._
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
import scala.io.Source
import edu.berkeley.nlp.coref.NumberGenderComputer

println("Hello, world!")
```

This is the error:

```
$ scala -cp "moarcoref-assembly-1.jar:." test.scala
/data/EvEn/nn_coref/modifiedBCS/test.scala:5: error: not found: value edu
import edu.berkeley.nlp.coref.NumberGenderComputer
       ^
one error found
```

I'm using version 2.11.6 and can't install a newer one.

```
$ scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.11.6 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL
```

Comment: It actually works for me, with Scala 2.11.7. And this is quite foundational, not working would be very weird. Try to use flag -verbose to get more information.

Comment: I logged in again and now it works. It's kinda weird... Thanks for your comment. How can I close this question?